# Как сделать плавную пунктированную анимацию c поворотом границы, такую как "марширующие муравьи"

Tags: css, css3, анимация, svg, css-animation

Я работаю над анимацией `css`, в которой используются зубья шестеренки  и цепь, но я не могу создать `smooth` последовательность вращения границы.

Вы можете видеть в [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n56dn5b/14/), как  я использую псевдоэлемент для создания эффекта вращения.Это делается путем переключения между пунктирной белой и пунктирной границей золотого цвета, из-за чего кажется, что "граница вращается".

**Вот код:**

```css
#one{
  -webkit-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */

}
#two{
  -webkit-animation: rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */

 position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:42px;
    width:80px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation{
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
@keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}

/******************************************************************************/

.chain{
    height:70px;
    width:80%;
    border:5px dashed gold;
    border-radius:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:40px;
          -webkit-animation: switchGoldBlackBorder 0.8s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    switchGoldBlackBorder 0.8s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      switchGoldBlackBorder 0.8s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         switchGoldBlackBorder 0.8s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}


@-webkit-keyframes switchBlackGoldBorder {
    0%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    49%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    50%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
    100%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
}
@-moz-keyframes switchBlackGoldBorder{
    0%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    49%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    50%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
    100%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
}
@-o-keyframes switchBlackGoldBorder {
    0%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    49%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    50%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
    100%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
}
@keyframes switchBlackGoldBorder {  
    0%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    49%   { border: 5px dashed transparent; }
    50%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
    100%   { border: 5px dashed gold; }
}



.chain:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height:70px;
    border-radius:30px;
    width:100%;
    top:-5px;
    left:-5px;
    border:5px solid gold;
    z-index:-1;
          -webkit-animation: switchBlackGoldBorder 0.8s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    switchBlackGoldBorder 0.8s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      switchBlackGoldBorder 0.8s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         switchBlackGoldBorder 0.8s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}

@-webkit-keyframes switchGoldBlackBorder {
  0%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    49%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    50%   { border: 5px solid white; }
    100%   { border: 5px solid white; }
}
@-moz-keyframes switchGoldBlackBorder{
  0%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    49%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    50%   { border: 5px solid white; }
    100%   { border: 5px solid white; }
}
@-o-keyframes switchGoldBlackBorder {
  0%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    49%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    50%   { border: 5px solid white; }
    100%   { border: 5px solid white; }
}
@keyframes switchGoldBlackBorder {  
    0%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    49%   { border: 5px solid gold; }
    50%   { border: 5px solid white; }
    100%   { border: 5px solid white; }
}
```

```html
<svg id="one" style="width:50px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
        <circle id="c" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="#808080" fill="none" stroke-width="25"/>
        <path id="d" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="16" d="M50 0, V15 M50 100, V85 M0 50, H15 M100 50, H85"/>
    </defs>    
    <use xlink:href="#c"/>
    <use xlink:href="#d"/>
    <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45, 50, 50)"/>
</svg>

<svg id="two" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <use xlink:href="#one"/>    
</svg>
<div class="chain"></div>
```

Итак, в нижней части `snippet` вы можете увидеть, как я создал эффект вращающейся цепочки, используя `keyframes`.

**Что бы я хотел в целом получить**

Подумайте о поперечном сечении конвейерной ленты и о том, как шестерни в конце ленты зацепляют её. Я пытаюсь воспроизвести это.
 То есть  впадины пунктирной ленты должны находиться на зубьях шестерни и тянуть её.

```css
#one{
  -webkit-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
border:5px dashed gold;
  border-radius:50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation{
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg id="one" style="width:50px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
        <circle id="c" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="#808080" fill="none" stroke-width="25"/>
        <path id="d" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="16" d="M50 0, V15 M50 100, V85 M0 50, H15 M100 50, H85"/>
    </defs>    
    <use xlink:href="#c"/>
    <use xlink:href="#d"/>
    <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45, 50, 50)"/>
</svg>
```

Но с золотыми черточками, чтобы они поместились между зубьями шестеренки, а также весь механизм занимал бы 80% ширины экрана (если это имеет смысл).

В конечном счете я хотел бы создать что-то вроде этого изображения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перевод вопроса: [How to make a smooth dashed border rotation animation like 'marching ants' @jbutler483](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28693659/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693659/how-to-make-a-smooth-dashed-border-rotation-animation-like-marching-ants/28694821#28694821

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Анимация цепи и зубьев шестеренки:

Полностью переписал код (`CSS` и `HTML`), теперь это:

- Короче (особенно CSS)
- Проще
- Вид механизма стал более реалистичный: исправил проблему
  синхронизации между цепочкой и шестеренками и добавил недостающую
  шестерню справа, потому что ваша цепь, казалось,- парила в воздухе:

```css
svg{width:100%;}
#chain_st{
  -webkit-animation: dash 1s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: dash 1s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: dash 1s infinite linear;
  animation: dash 1s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
}
@-moz-keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
}
@-o-keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
}
@keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
}
```

```html
<svg id="one" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 30">
  <defs>
    <circle id="c" cx="20" cy="20" r="4" stroke="#808080" fill="none" stroke-width="4"/>
    <path id="d" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="2" d="M20 13 V16 M27 20 H24 M20 27 V24 M13 20 H16"/>
    <g id="cog">
      <use xlink:href="#c"/>
      <use xlink:href="#d"/>
      <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45 20 20)"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0,-7), scale(0.8), rotate(22.5 8 8)">
    <use xlink:href="#cog">
      <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
                    attributeName="transform"
                    type="rotate"
                    from="-22.5 20 20"
                    to="337.5 20 20"
                    dur="8s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </use>
  </g>
  <path id="chain_st" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="2.6 2.45" d="M21.3 13.5 H20 C11.4 13.5 11.4 26.5 20 26.5 H80 C89 26.5 89 13.5 80.8 13.5z" />
  <use class="rot" xlink:href="#cog">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
                    attributeName="transform"
                    type="rotate"
                    from="22.5 20 20"
                    to="-337.5 20 20"
                    dur="8s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
  <g transform="translate(60.3 0)">
    <use class="" xlink:href="#cog">
      <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
                    attributeName="transform"
                    type="rotate"
                    from="22.5 20 20"
                    to="-337.5 20 20"
                    dur="8s"
                    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </use>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Подход тот же, что и анимация угла поворота для зубцов и смещение штрихов для цепи.
Я настроил синхронизацию между двумя анимациями, чтобы она выглядела так, как будто шестерни тянут цепь.

### Browser support :

Поскольку `IE` [не поддерживает элемент](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate#Browser_compatibility) `svg animate`, я также сделал эту версию анимации с библиотекой [snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/), которая также поддерживает `IE9` и более (протестирована в `IE9` с [crossbrowsertesting](http://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/test-center)).

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/emroGg) с поддержкой IE

```js
var cont   = new Snap('#svg'),
    chain  = cont.select('#chain'),
    cogAcw = cont.select('#cog_acw'),
    cogCw  = cont.select('#cog_cw'),
    speed  = 500;  // Lower this number to make the animation faster

function infChain(el) {
    var len = el.getTotalLength();
    el.attr({"stroke-dasharray": len/62,"stroke-dashoffset": 0});
    el.animate({"stroke-dashoffset": -len/31}, speed, mina.linear, infChain.bind(null, el));
}
function rotateAcw(el) {
    el.transform('r22.5,20,20');
    el.animate({ transform: 'r-22.5,20,20' }, speed, mina.linear, rotateAcw.bind( null, el));
}
function rotateCw(el) {
    el.transform('r0,20,20');
    el.animate({ transform: 'r45,20,20' }, speed, mina.linear, rotateCw.bind( null, el));
}
infChain(chain);
rotateAcw(cogAcw);
rotateCw(cogCw);
```

```css
svg {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 30">
    <defs>
        <circle id="c" cx="20" cy="20" r="4" stroke="#808080" fill="none" stroke-width="4" />
        <path id="d" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="2" d="M20 13 V16 M27 20 H24 M20 27 V24 M13 20 H16" />
        <g id="cog_acw">
            <use xlink:href="#c" /><use xlink:href="#d" />
            <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45 20 20)" />
        </g>  
        <g id="cog_cw">
            <use xlink:href="#c" /><use xlink:href="#d" />
            <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45 20 20)" />
        </g>  
    </defs>
    <path id="chain" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000" fill="transparent" 
    d="M21.3 13.5 H20 C11.4 13.5 11.4 26.5 20 26.5 H80 C89.4 26.5 89.4 13.5 80.8 13.5z" />
    <use  xlink:href="#cog_acw" />
    <use  transform="translate(60.5 0), rotate(19,20,20)" xlink:href="#cog_acw" />
    <use  transform="translate(-4.5 -4.5),scale(.8), rotate(0,20,20)" xlink:href="#cog_cw" />    
</svg>
```

**Для современных браузеров**

```css
svg{width:100%;}
#chain_st{
  -webkit-animation: dash 1s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: dash 1s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: dash 1s infinite linear;
  animation: dash 1s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
}
@-moz-keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
}
@-o-keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
}
@keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
}
```

```html
<svg id="one" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 30">
  <defs>
    <circle id="c" cx="20" cy="20" r="4" stroke="#808080" fill="none" stroke-width="4"/>
    <path id="d" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="2" d="M20 13 V16 M27 20 H24 M20 27 V24 M13 20 H16"/>
    <g id="cog">
      <use xlink:href="#c"/>
      <use xlink:href="#d"/>
      <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45 20 20)"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0,-7), scale(0.8), rotate(22.5 8 8)">
    <use xlink:href="#cog">
      <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="-22.5 20 20" to="337.5 20 20" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </use>
  </g>
  <path id="chain_st" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="2.6 2.45" d="M21.3 13.5 H20 C11.4 13.5 11.4 26.5 20 26.5 H80 C89 26.5 89 13.5 80.8 13.5z" />
  <use class="rot" xlink:href="#cog">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate"from="22.5 20 20" to="-337.5 20 20" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
  <g transform="translate(60.3 0)">
    <use class="" xlink:href="#cog">
      <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="22.5 20 20" to="-337.5 20 20" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </use>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Предложения к коду автора вопроса:**

Вы можете использовать другой `svg dashed path` и анимировать свойство `dash-offset` с помощью `keyframe animation`.

Это можно и нужно упростить / настроить для использования в "real world":

- Все элементы могут быть помещены в один тэг `<svg>` (это упростит
  задачу, и оба элемента шестеренка + цепь могут совместно изменять
  размер)
- Синхронизация между цепью и зубчатым колесом не идеальна, и скорость
  / размер цепи необходимо подкорректировать.

Прим. переводчика

Ниже в сниппете отвечающий подправил оригинальный код, который был в вопросе топика

```css
#one {
  -webkit-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
#two {
  -webkit-animation: rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 42px;
  width: 80px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateAntiClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
/******************************************************************************/

#chain {
  width: 650px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  left: 35px;
}
.chain_st {
  stroke-dasharray: 1.5;
  stroke-dashoffset: 10;
  -webkit-animation: dash 18s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: dash 18s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: dash 18s infinite linear;
  animation: dash 18s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="one" style="width:50px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <circle id="c" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="#808080" fill="none" stroke-width="25" />
    <path id="d" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="16" d="M50 0, V15 M50 100, V85 M0 50, H15 M100 50, H85" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#c" />
  <use xlink:href="#d" />
  <use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(45, 50, 50)" />
</svg>

<svg id="two" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <use xlink:href="#one" />
</svg>
<svg id="chain" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 70 10">
  <path class="chain_st" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#000" fill="transparent" d="M60 1 Q65 1 65 5 Q65 9 60 9 H6 Q1 9 1 5 Q1 1 6 1z" />
</svg>
```

Перевод ответа: [How to make a smooth dashed border rotation animation like 'marching ants' @web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28694821/7394871)

Answer (score 6):

**Примечание.**

Я переделал всю анимацию в `box-shadow`, потому что использование `dashed borders` не имеет согласованного вывода во всех браузерах.

### Работает

**.. и работает кроссбраузерно.**
FF 5+, GC 4+, IE9+, Safari 4+, Opera 12.1+

Вы можете попробовать это с помощью `box-shadow`:

- Чтобы сделать зубья шестеренок, используйте `box-shadow` с
  отрицательным `spread radius`. Размер моей шестеренки был, например:
  `50px` , поэтому, чтобы использовать `box-shadow` с `d = 8px`, я
  установил `-46px`, как `spread radius`.
- Я разместил зубья шестеренки, используя координаты `geo`, и сделал
  только `8` зубьев для упрощения.
- Теперь для прямого участка конвейера, нам нужно узнать расстояние
  между зубьями . Мы получаем это следующим образом:
- `2*pi*(r шестеренки) / кол. зубьев = (pi * r) / 4

  результат = (55 * 3.1415) / 4 = 43 (приблизительно)`
  Я взял радиус 55, потому что зубья имеют радиус `4px` и находятся на расстоянии `1px` от окружности шестерни.
  прим. переводчика: 
  `55` - это диаметр.
- Для выравнивания верхних и нижних прямых участков ленты конвейера, 
  необходимо их перевести на любое кратное  расстояние. Для моих
  шестеренок я установил их на `43px`.

### Каркас

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hpLqmfs8/)

```css
   body {
background: rgba(25,80,175, 0.4);
}
.rect {
height: 116px;
width: 401px;
border-radius: 58px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.rect:before, .rect:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 46px; /*50-half width*/
height: 8px;
width: 8px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: transparent;
box-shadow: 43px 0 0 0 white, 86px 0 0 0 white, 129px 0 0 0 white, 172px 0 0 0 white, 215px 0 0 0 white, 258px 0 0 0 white, 301px 0 0 0 white;
-webkit-animation: apple 0.3s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: apple 0.3s linear infinite;
animation: apple 0.3s linear infinite;
}
.rect:before {
top: 0px;
}
.rect:after {
bottom: 0px;
-webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
-moz-animation-direction: reverse;
animation-direction: reverse;
}
@-webkit-keyframes apple {
0% {-webkit-transform: translatex(0px);}
100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
@-moz-keyframes apple {
0% {-moz-transform: translatex(0px);}
100% {-moz-transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
@keyframes apple {
0% {transform: translatex(0px);}
100% {transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
.left, .right {
content: '';
position: relative;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border-radius: 50px;
background-color: #222;
box-shadow: 0 55px 0 -46px white, 55px 0 0 -46px white, 0 -55px 0 -46px white, -55px 0 0 -46px white,
    39px 39px 0 -46px white, -39px -39px 0 -46px white, 39px -39px 0 -46px white, -39px 39px 0 -46px white;
-webkit-animation: mango 2.4s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: mango 2.4s linear infinite;
animation: mango 2.4s linear infinite;
}
.left {
top: -108px;
left: 0px;
}
.right {
top: -208px;
left: 301px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mango {
0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes mango {
0% {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% {-moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@keyframes mango {
0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

### Финальная версия

... **с шестеренками.** Цепочка в настоящее время `dotted dashed`!

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4jemr2uo/)

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
}
.rect {
    height: 120px;
    width: 401px;
    border-radius: 58px;
    position: relative;
}

.rect:before, .rect:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px; /*50-half width*/
    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: 43px 0 0 0 gold, 86px 0 0 0 gold, 129px 0 0 0 gold, 172px 0 0 0 gold, 215px 0 0 0 gold, 258px 0 0 0 gold, 301px 0 0 0 gold, 344px 0 0 0 gold; /*keep adding 43 to x-axis*/
    -webkit-animation: apple 0.6s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: apple 0.6s linear infinite;
    animation: apple 0.6s linear infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.rect:before {
    top: 0px;
}
.rect:after {
    bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
@-webkit-keyframes apple {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
@-moz-keyframes apple {
    0% {-moz-transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {-moz-transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
@keyframes apple {
    0% {transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
.left, .right {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: mango 4.8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: mango 4.8s linear infinite;
    animation: mango 4.8s linear infinite;
}
.left {
    top: -110px;
    left: 0px;
}
.right {
    top: -210px;
    left: 344px;
}
.left:before, .left:after, .right:before, .right:after {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gold;
}
.left:before, .right:before {
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 0 0 gold, -50px 50px 0 0 gold, 0 100px 0 0 gold;
    top: -10px;
    left: 40px;
}
.left:after, .right:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 5px;
    left: 76px;
    box-shadow: 0px 100px 0 0 gold, 50px 50px 0 0 gold, -50px 50px 0 0 gold;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mango {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes mango {
    0% {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@keyframes mango {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
.cover {
    height: 104px;
    width: 446px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    top: -312px;
    left; -2px;
    
}
.gear, .gear2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: dimgray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: gear 4.8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: gear 4.8s linear infinite;
    animation: gear 4.8s linear infinite;
}
.gear {
    top: -414px;
  
}
.gear2 {
    top: -514px;
    left: 345px;
}
.gear:before, .gear:after, .gear2:before, .gear2:after {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: dimgray;
    
}
.gear:before, .gear2:before {
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 0 0 dimgray, -50px 50px 0 0 dimgray, 0 100px 0 0 dimgray;
    top: -10px;
    left: 40px;
}
.gear:after, .gear2:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 5px;
    left: 76px;
    box-shadow: 0px 100px 0 0 dimgray, 50px 50px 0 0 dimgray, -50px 50px 0 0 dimgray;
}
@-webkit-keyframes gear {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-337.5deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes gear {
    0% {-moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);}
    100% {-moz-transform: rotate(-337.5deg);}
}
@keyframes gear {
    0% {transform: rotate(22.5deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(-337.5deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="cover"></div>
<div class="gear"></div>
<div class="gear2"></div>
```

### Финальная версия (закругленные зубья шестеренки)

```css
.rect {
    height: 120px;
    width: 401px;
    border-radius: 58px;
    position: relative;
}
.rect:before, .rect:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px; /*50-half width*/
    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    box-shadow: 43px 0 0 0 gold, 86px 0 0 0 gold, 129px 0 0 0 gold, 172px 0 0 0 gold, 215px 0 0 0 gold, 258px 0 0 0 gold, 301px 0 0 0 gold, 344px 0 0 0 gold; /*keep adding 43 to x-axis*/
    -webkit-animation: translate 0.6s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: translate 0.6s linear infinite;
    animation: translate 0.6s linear infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.rect:before {top: 0px;}
.rect:after {
    bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
@-webkit-keyframes translate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
@-moz-keyframes translate {
    0% {-moz-transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {-moz-transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
@keyframes translate {
    0% {transform: translatex(0px);}
    100% {transform: translateX(-43px);}
}
.left, .right {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 4.8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotate 4.8s linear infinite;
    animation: rotate 4.8s linear infinite;
}
.left {
    top: -110px; left: 0px;
}
.right {
    top: -210px; left: 344px;
}
.left:before, .left:after, .right:before, .right:after {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: gold;
}
.left:before, .right:before {
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 0 0 gold, -50px 50px 0 0 gold, 0 100px 0 0 gold;
    top: -10px;
    left: 40px;
}
.left:after, .right:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 5px;
    left: 76px;
    box-shadow: 0px 100px 0 0 gold, 50px 50px 0 0 gold, -50px 50px 0 0 gold;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    0% {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
.cover {
    height: 104px;
    width: 446px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    top: -312px;
    left; -2px;
}
.gear, .gear2, .gear3 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 35px dimgray, inset 0 0 0px 40px #444;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 4.8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotate 4.8s linear infinite;
    animation: rotate 4.8s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.gear {top: -414px;}
.gear2 {top: -514px; left: 345px;}
.gear:before, .gear:after, .gear2:before, .gear2:after,  .gear3:before, .gear3:after {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    content: '';
    border-radius: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background: dimgray;
}
.gear:before, .gear2:before, .gear3:before {
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 0 0 dimgray, -50px 50px 0 0 dimgray, 0 100px 0 0 dimgray;
    top: -10px; left: 40px;
}
.gear:after, .gear2:after, .gear3:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 5px; left: 76px;
    box-shadow: 0px 100px 0 0 dimgray, 50px 50px 0 0 dimgray, -50px 50px 0 0 dimgray;
}
.gear3 {
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    top: -504px;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="cover"></div>
<div class="gear"></div>
<div class="gear2"></div>
<div class="gear3"></div>
```

[FIDDLE - ROUNDED TEETH](http://jsfiddle.net/gdh6wa7w/)

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**. Чтобы увеличить скорость анимации, вам просто нужно пропорционально уменьшить продолжительность анимации каждого элемента.

[Fiddle (fast)](http://jsfiddle.net/t80d5oy1/)

Перевод ответа: [How to make a smooth dashed border rotation animation like 'marching ants'@The Pragmatick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28718587/7394871)